# Testing angular controller with jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using angular since a couple of weeks and I'd like to introduce serious tests for controllers and filters.

I tried to write tests using jasmine but nothing seems to work. I then tried to reproduce the tests described in the official tutorials without success.

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/rortelli/K2BAH/1/

Thanks in advance

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []); 
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
     'age': 1},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
     'age': 2},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
     'age': 3}
  ];
});

describe('PhoneCat controllers', function() {

  describe('PhoneListCtrl', function(){
    var scope, ctrl;

    beforeEach(module('phonecatApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
      scope = {};
      ctrl = $controller('PhoneListCtrl', {$scope:scope});
    }));

    it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', function() {
      expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
    });

    it('should set the default value of orderProp model', function() {
      expect(scope.orderProp).toBe('age');
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: How could we help? Describe how you run your tests, what your karma config file looks like, and what output you get when running karma.

Comment: run the jsfiddle example and you will see that it fails. The returned error is "ReferenceError: module is not defined". I've included the angular-mocks.js file that will expose the module function.

Comment: I overlooked the external resources definition, so I deleted my answer... but apparently it has something to do with the resource definition, because if the script is defined directly in the markup, it works as we can se here - http://jsfiddle.net/K2BAH/4/

Answer (score 0):

Its the order of loading scripts that's failing the fiddle with "ReferenceError: module is not defined"

Remove both angular files and add them again to the bottom of the list, then your fiddle works.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. include angular-mocks.js
2. scope.orderProp doesnt exist in the spec
   so just add it to the controller and then you will have 2 successful
   test like you see below.

http://jsfiddle.net/zNnvx/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-mocks.js"></script>

$scope.orderProp = 'age';
```